# can you get stats from the twitter api

Tags: twitter, twitter-rest-api

is there a way to get the impressions of tweets generated through the api? or the most retweeted tweet that an app/api generated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this answer by a Twitter developer here](https://twittercommunity.com/t/twitter-analytics-api/27296/2), there doesn't seem to be a way to programmatically access the data from http://analytics.twitter.com.